# Design Pane doesn't load in Windows Phone 8 Application Development in Visual Studio 2012 Pro

Tags: windows-phone-8

The design Page for Windows Phone 8 Application devlopment in Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 8 doesn't load i.e. the file MainPage.xaml just shows the following error:

An Unhandled Exception Has Occured

System.TypeInitializationException .......

It won't reload either
by clicking on
Reload The Designer

Comment: can you provide more information about the exception it displays? it would be very helpful.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException
The document failed to open.
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)

Comment: I'm sorry, then I don't think I can help you. Have you tried googling yet? Search up the exception.

Comment: Or try opening a new solution and copying all your current code there. Your solution might be corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download vs2012 update 2 ..
it will solve the problem..

Answer (score 1):

I'm was facing this same issue last week, and fortunately in my case (i hope yours too) the problem was solved when renew my free windows 8 developer license. To do so, run power shell as administrator and execute Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration, this will start the license renovation process. When completed, click the Reload Again button on the VS2012 designer surface, and the designer should successfully load.